# Possible to create a CXF non blocking Webservice

Tags: web-services, jaxb, cxf

**Is it possible to create non blocking CFX Webservice?**

Using version 2.3.3 i am trying to just the Async functions but if i try 1000 connections simultaniusly I get either:

```
Connection closed, 
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

I am running my webservices on a jboss 6.1.

Is there any good guide for this ? Do I need todo anything on server side or is it enough when it comes to async to just generate them on client side?

I am using this code on client side.

```
Response<SearchResponse> response =  getDeliveryInWebservice().searchAsync(getCredentials(), ss);

while(!response.isDone()){
    Thread.sleep(50);
}
SearchResponse searchResponse =  response.get();
```

//Trind